# Chrome App Lifecycle

Tags: lifecycle, google-chrome-app

I'm reading through [Chrome App Lifecycle](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle). The model looks very simple. There's an `onLaunch` and `onSuspend`.

A few questions:

1) Is it possible to detect a transition from foreground to background?

2) Does Chrome persist any state automatically before moving to the background?

3) Does Chrome snap a capture of the app's window before moving to the background?

4) Does the same apply to Chrome [Packaged Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yo'll only receive `onSuspend` event right before event page become inactive. If you want to know when the user close app's window you need to listen for page unload event in the app an inform event page about the fact (using chrome.runtime API).

2) If you set "id" parameter for chrome.app.window.create options object, Chrome will persist window state: width, height, top and left position and screen number and restore it during next app bootstrap. You can override this behavior setting your own values in chrome.app.window.create method.

3) As far as I know - no.

4) No. It is different kind of apps.

Comment: +1, but just a small note on point #4 that New style Chrome Apps are still Packaged apps.  The link from the question specifically pointed at the legacy docs, but I don't want anyone to think that "Chrome Packaged Apps" implies old style.

Comment: You are right. However legacy apps have different lifecycle (event page vs background page), different set of API's and so on. So in a way they are different except that they have similar basis.

Comment: Thanks @jarrodek. Regarding (2) and (3): the worry is Chrome will persist or "freeze dry" some sensitive data. So I'm clear - no screen captures to make the task switch seem more responsive, no persisting usernames and passwords from text boxes (input boxes), no scrapping of PDFs, etc.

Comment: Thanks @mmocny. Sorry about the stale link. Its hard to find current docs when webmasters turn everything into a moving target (I'm still searching for the W3C's permissions that are being considered for standardization in web apps). Please feel free to update the link if you have a more current page.

Comment: @jww Chrome does not store any of your data unless you told him to do so. So don't worry about that.